# cordova-plugin-file not uploading cdvfile:// path to the server

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-file

It is for sure that `cordova-plugin-file-transfer` is not required any more for transferring files from a local path to a remote server.

I am able to get the `cdvfile://` path and even display the same on a DOM but I don't know how to upload it using just the file plugin and not the file transfer.

Here is my code so far. I have used the plugins:

- cordova-plugin-camera
- cordova-plugin-file
- cordova-plugin-crop

Code:

```
function clickFirstProfilePhoto(){

    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
    correctOrientation:true, 
    targetWidth:1024, 
    targetHeight: 1024, 
    destinationType: 
    destinationType.FILE_URI});
}
```

Now the success function:

```
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
           
plugins.crop.promise(imageData).then(function success (imageFinal) {
          // Success.
          //alert(imageFinal);
          var fileURI = imageFinal.substr(imageFinal.lastIndexOf('?') + 1);
          //alert(fileURI);
          resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageFinal, function(entry) {
          $("#picPreviewBox").html('<img src="'+entry.toInternalURL()+'" width="100%" />');

            var t=""
            t=t+'<div class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">Save</div> <div class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">discard</div>';
            $("#buttons_save_discard").html(t);

            
          });


}).catch(function fail (err) {
          // fail
 $.alert("Seems your phone resources are too low to proceed further");
        });

 }
```

Using `entry.toInternalURL()` in the DOM is displaying the picture captured and then cropped but then how to upload it to a url on the server along with some parameters?

Comment: You should consider getting the base64 instead of a fileURI and send base64 data to the back end, will save you a lot of troubles

Comment: Many thanks for replying! I highly appreciate that! But you see here's the catch

1) If I return DATA_URL (i.e. base64 format) instead of FILE_URI from the plugin the default camera plugin crop function fails on maximum devices. Also, cordova-plugin-crop doesn't work with base64 hence I have to return the data back to use in the form of a native path or a cdvfile:/// path

2) If I use FILE_URI and convent the path to base64 using htm2canvas or whatever then it takes huge time for the app to process it and upload it to the server, also the php file takes time to convert it into an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I now have the solution. After getting the file path, I am converting the same to base64 and then uploading it to my PHP file on the server to save it as an image, here is the code:

```
    function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
               
    plugins.crop.promise(imageData).then(function success (imageFinal) {
              // Success.
              //alert(imageFinal);
              var fileURI = imageFinal.substr(imageFinal.lastIndexOf('?') + 1);
              //alert(fileURI);
              resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageFinal, function(entry) {
                
                $("#loadSignup3Data").html('<img src="'+entry.toInternalURL()+'" id="imagePreviewBox" width="200p" height="200" style="border-radius:50%;" />');
               // $("#picPreview").modal('show');
                $("#picOptions").modal('hide');
                $("#picPreviewBox").html('<img src="'+entry.toInternalURL()+'" id="imagePreviewBox" width="200p" height="200"/>');
                //$("#picPreview").modal('show');
               $.confirm({
                title: 'Please confirm!',
                content: 'Do you wish to save it as your profile picture?',
                buttons: {
                    confirm: function () {
                        
                        $("#ultraLoader").show();
                        html2canvas(document.querySelector("#imagePreviewBox")).then(canvas => {
                            var renderedImg = canvas.toDataURL();
                            var id = $("#pictureUploadID").val();
                            var deviceid = device.uuid;
                          
          $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "https://my_url_which_i_must_not_show/saveFirstProfilePic.php",
          dataType:'json',
          data: {base64Img: renderedImg, id:id, deviceid:deviceid},
          success: function(response){
             $("#ultraLoader").hide();
             $.alert("Your profile picture has been saved");
             location.href = "Dashboard.html?id="+id;
             }
            });

          });
             
   },cancel: function () {
    navigator.notification.alert('You chose not to save the picture. Please take another picture or select one from your phone gallery');
       $("#ultraLoader").hide();
                 }
                }
            });
```